# How to enable tty input even with pipe?

Tags: shell, pipe, tty

I need to modify the output of a program that asks for tty input.  When I pipe the output of the program to a utility such as `sed` however, lines of input don't show.

As a specific if trivial example: I'd like to take the normal Scala input, which includes a REPL prompt:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_60).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala>
```

And change all occurrences of `Java` to `Mocha`:

```
$ scala | sed 's/Java/Mocha/g'
Welcome to Scala 2.12.3 (Mocha HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Mocha 1.8.0_60).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.
```

The problem is that neither the last line (`scala>`) nor any keyboard input typed is shown until after `[Enter]` is pressed.  I'd like for the second version to behave as the first, only with the `sed` substitution (and not substitution of keyboard input, of course).  Is this possible?

(A portable solution is best, of course, but in case the only solution is shell- or distro-specific, I'd ideally like Zsh and BSD.  Thanks.)

Answer (score 0):

Buffering will be a problem, as `scala` may use block-based buffering on account of the pipe (instead of the default terminal line-based buffering, see [`setvbuf(3)`](http://man.openbsd.org/man3/setvbuf.3)) and also buffering done by `sed` (or anything else in the pipeline). You could try slapping `stdbuf` on everything, toss portability, and pray that those `LD_PRELOAD` monkey patches work; another option would instead be to run the REPL under a PTY, feed user input to that, and substitute the output before sending it along. This here shows SBCL as `scala` was delightfully non-functional on my machine.

```
$ ./mochanichize sbcl 
This is SBCL 1.3.20, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
* (print "Java")

"Mocha" 
"Mocha"
* (exit)
$
```

And the code for `mochanichize`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

package require Tcl 8.5

proc mochanichize {fh} {
   global godot
   set somedata [read $fh]
   if {[eof $fh]} { close $fh; set godot 1; return; }
   regsub -all {\mJava\M} $somedata {Mocha} somedata
   puts -nonewline $somedata
}

proc sendtoprog {from to} {
   # TODO support ^D but that's more complicated
   puts -nonewline $to [read $from]
}

# no echo on PTY command we're running (soas not to duplicate what is
# echo'd back to the user via the user tty)
set stty_init -echo

if {[catch {spawn -noecho {*}$argv} err]} { puts stderr $err; exit 1 }

chan configure $spawn_id -blocking 0 -buffersize 1
chan event $spawn_id readable [list mochanichize $spawn_id]

chan configure stdin -blocking 0 -buffersize 1
chan configure stdout -blocking 0 -buffersize 1
chan event stdin readable [list sendtoprog stdin $spawn_id]

# TODO better handle ^Z this goes all meh on it
trap SIG_IGN SIGTSTP

vwait godot
```